# Christoffel symbols is not reparametrization invariant.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, parametrization

Let $\sigma(u, v) = (u \cos v, u \sin v, 0)$ be the polar parametrization of a
plane. Compute the Christofell symbols and show that it is not reparametrization invariant.

I have computed the Christofell symbols but how to show that it is not reparametrization invariant?

The Christofell symbols are $0$ and $\frac1u$.

Need some hints to proceed with the problem!

Comment: What is the other parametrization for example? Have you checked $ (u,v,0)?$  or $ (u+v,u-v , 0) ?$

Answer (score 0):

Isometric mappings leave Christoffel symbols unchanged.

Polar grid alone is not the only net to parametrize a  plane.

Any arbitrary manner of changing distances on the plane by a new metric may leave zero Gauss curvature and integral curvature (trivial case) unchanged but not the parametrization itself !